# need help in complex numbers argument

Tags: complex-analysis

Any help appreciated please,

use an argand diagram to find, in the form a+bi, the complex numbers which satisfy the following pairs of equations.

arg(z+2)=1/2π, argz=2/3π

Thanks

Comment: mmmm... pie. Sorry, but I had to comment. I will edit your question to make it look better. You wrote 1/2 pie, does that mean $\frac12 \pi e$ or just $\frac12\pi?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z= -2 +2\sqrt{3} i$ -- to see why,  first note that $arg(z+2)=\frac{1}{2}\pi$ means $z+2$ is on the positive imaginary axis, so $z$ is (in rectangular terms) 2 units left of that, so $a=-2$ (where $z=a+bi$).  Now thinking of $z$ in polar form, the given condition $arg(z)=\frac{2}{3}\pi$ means $z=r e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}$ for whatever value of $r$ puts $z$ 2 units left of the vertical axis -- but noting the 30-60-90 triangles associated with $z$ (e.g. drop a vertical from $z$ down to the negative real axis), it must be the case that $r=4$.  Converting to rectangular gives the answer above, or equivalently (again noting 30-60-90 triangle stuff), the vertical leg of the triangle is $\sqrt{3}$ times the length of the horizontal leg.

Comment: i m unclear as to what you mean by 30-60-90 triangles ? and secondly what does re^2/3πi stand for

Comment: 30-60-90 refers to degree measures in a right triangle, radian measures $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  In that triangle, the three sides have length 2 (hypotenuse), 1 (short leg opposite $\frac{\pi}{6}$ angle), and $\sqrt{3}$ (leg opposite $\frac{\pi}{3}$ angle).  The triangle I described is similar, with scaling factor 2.  As for the $r e^{i\theta}$, that's exponential-polar form, from $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i \sin\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z = r_1e^{i\frac{2}{3}\pi}$$

$$z+2 = r_2e^{i\frac{1}{2}\pi}$$

$$2 = (z+2)-z=\dots$$